# hibernate foreign key

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I have a `Task` table. It has a foreign key `task_status_id`.
I have a `TaskStatus` table. It has two primary keys: `task_status_id` and `lang_id`.
I have a `LanguageType` table. It has a primary key `lang_id`.

I want to know how to map this relationship in hibernate.

Comment: Do you mean TaskStatus.task_status_id is the primary key and TaskStatus.lang_id is a foreign key? Otherwise, you seem to have a single-column foreign key (Task.task_status_id) referring to a multi-column primary key.

Comment: yes, and no, TaskStatus has two primary key, task_status_id and lang_id. But, lang_id is also a foreign key.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will probably do what you want:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_status_id")
    TaskStatus status;
}

@Entity
public class TaskStatus {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "task_status_id")
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "lang_id")
    LanguageType languageType;
}

@Entity
public class LanguageType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lang_id")
    private int id;
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. I'm wondering how to map this relationship in hbm file.

Comment: I modified taskStatus.hbm like this, but it seems doesn't work.`<many-to-one name="taskStatus" class="com.entity.TaskStatus">
            <column name="task_status_id"></column>
            <column name="lang_id"></column>
  </many-to-one>`